PayPal GIROPAY is automatically cancelling the orders
In Germany there is a payment method called giropay.
Unfortunately, when I integrate them one-to-one according to the PayPal documentation, an error occurs.
The giroypay button is rendered normally. However, after I click on it, it loads briefly, jumps to PayPal, and then logs in the console that the order was canceled. Can anyone explain why this is happening?
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<?= $env['paypal_client_id'] ?>&components=buttons,payment-fields,marks,funding-eligibility&enable-funding=giropay&currency=EUR"></script>

<div id="giropay-btn"></div>

<script>
paypal.Buttons({
  fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.GIROPAY,
  style: {
    label: "pay",
  },
  createOrder() {
    return fetch("/my-server/create-paypal-order", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((order) => order.id);
  },
  onCancel(data, actions) {
    console.log(`Order Canceled - ID: ${data.orderID}`);
  },
  onError(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}).render("#giropay-btn");
</script>

If I leave out the fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.GIROPAY, in my code, the normal PayPal buttons, among other things, are correctly rendered; the payment then works with giropay.

You are missing an onApprove() function to capture the payment after payer approval.

Yes, I know, I took that out for clarity. Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question

If that is there, then the described behavior of the PayPal window opening and closing immediately will happen when "/my-server/create-paypal-order does not return a valid Order ID. Debug/troubleshoot with the dev tools Network tab open.

i can the in the network tab that it returns a valid order id.
That is also not the problem

maybe it just can't be tested in sandbox mode, then
